# .NET execute multiple static constructors on startup

Tags: c#, multithreading, static, startup, synchronous

Let's say app startup relies on the following pattern :

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    void App_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        var config = new ConfigSettings();
        var dbObjects = new DbObjects();
        // many other such static classes


public class ConfigSettings
{
    static ConfigSettings()
    {
        // long-running workload 1
        // read huge xml file parse and populate cache
    }
}

public class DbObjects
{
    static DbObjects()
    {
        // long-running workload 2 : 
        // query db for thousands of objects populate to cache
    }
}
```

Obviously this pattern is problematic for many reasons such as efficiency, troubleshooting, user-experience, etc.

But my question is does CLR for efficiency potentially simultaneously run code in multiple static ctors ?

Or does the CLR always guarantee that workload 1 completes before workload 2 begins, etc.

Obviously that would be guaranteed for :

```
public class DbObjects
{
    static DbObjects()
    {
        var config = new ConfigSettings();
        var c = new Connection(config.DbConnectionString);
        // etc.
    }
}
```

But what about cases where the ctors' code doesn't interact ?

And what about a startup code-path that kicks-off multiple long-running async processes each of which refers to one or more static classes for first time ?  So it's non-deterministic the order of first reference. In this case would the CLR queue the static ctors ?

Comment: For your scenario, the database connection string to use in `DbObjects` is read from `ConfigSettings`, right? So, you want `DbObjects` to be initialized ONLY after reading settings. Is this correct?

Comment: `But my question is does CLR for efficiency potentially simultaneously run code in multiple static constructors ?` No. You can test this easily for yourself by writing to a log at the start and end of each of the static constructors.

Comment: I have tried running a couple of testing examples on my local and you are correct. Each static constructor acts independently of the others. How about writing a base class e.g `AppBase` that will have a static contructor to load the most basic settings that your app requires at first then have other classes that inherit from it e.g `public class ConfigSettings : AppBase`

So when you initialize both settings and dbobjects, the base contructor executes only ONCE and get's reused.

Would like to see if you agree.

Comment: Absolutely agree there's far better init mechanisms that what I'm working with presently :) I'm trying to debug a pre-existing system.

Answer (score 1):

.NET will not spontaneously spawn new threads for your code. The thread that accesses the class first is the one that gets to run the static constructor at that point. If two threads access it at the same time, one will win and the other will wait until the first one is done.

Comment: Ok but let's say the app itself kicks off new threads is it possible for thread2 to begin executing class2 ctor code while thread1 is still executing class1 ctor code ?  Or does the CLR queue-up static ctors in order they were first encountered and then execute in order ?

Comment: @BaltoStar - Good question. Why don't you try and see? Add some `Thread.Sleep()` calls to slow down the constructors and force parallelism. My guess is that they will run in parallel, unless they depend on each other, in which case one of them will stall midway to wait for the other to complete. You can probably get a deadlock if you try hard enough. ;)